# Why not working in app.component but in auth.guard?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I am not understanding why same code is not working from app.component which is perfectly worked in auth.guard.

I have written some code to check that user is Logged In to server or not and used canActivate in routing defined auth.guard like below

**Routing**

```
{ path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

**AuthGuard**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService} from './services/auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router:Router) { }
          canActivate(next:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot) {
              return this.authService.isAuth().map(e => {
                  if (e) {
                      return true;
                  }
              }).catch(() => {
                  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                  return Observable.of(false);
              });
          }
    }
```

It is working fine but not working in AppComponent
**AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './views/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './styles/app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Jiffy';
  status:boolean;
  swap:boolean=true;
  constructor(authService:AuthService, private router:Router){
    return this.authService.isAuth().map(e => {
        if (e) {
            return true;
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return Observable.of(false);
    });
  }
}
```

I am not understanding why it is **not** working here?

**Error**

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuth'
>   of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuth' of undefined at
>   new AppComponent

**AuthService**

```
  isAuth(){
        return this.http.get("/account/check")
        .map(function(res){
          return status=res.json().status;
        });
    }
```

**Express Server with Passport**

```
router.get('/check',  function(req, res,next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    return  res.send({"status":true});
  }
    return res.send({"status":false});
});
```

Comment: Any more details you can give us? Logging any errors? What is the result of `isAuth` in each case?

Comment: Edited About service and Server method. I am using Passport it is returning true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `public` or `private` to the parameters inside the constructor if you want to get them with `this` inside your component.

```
constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router:Router)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that `authService` is undefined. Have you declared `AuthService` as a provider in your app.module?

Comment: I think you need to add the `private` keyword in the constructor, otherwise Angular won't know to inject the service.